# registerReceiver() not using the BroadcastReceiver instantiated by the Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I've made a class, `MediaButtonReceiver` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. In my activity's `onCreate()`, I instantiate it, and set the activity as a listener which it notifies:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
intentFilter.setPriority(999);
MediaButtonReceiver mediaButtonReceiver = new MediaButtonReceiver();
mediaButtonReceiver.setListener(this);
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver, intentFilter);
```

The problem is, when a media button is pressed, it seems to instantiate the `MediaButtonReceiver` rather than use the one created by my activity, because its reference to the activity is null.

This is what I have in the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.example.myapp.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I have tried removing the receiver from the manifest, but then the app never gets the signal when a media button is pressed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "but then the app never gets the signal when a media button is pressed" -- well, it will only get "the signal" when your activity is in the foreground. What behavior are you aiming for?

Comment: onReceive() doesn't get called even when the activity is in the foreground